Why does VGG trained from scratch throw an error when input channes are changed to more than three?
Using this guide on how to implemenent VGG19 from scratch, I changed the input shape but gives error. How do I modify this layer to accept images with more than 3 channels?
Changed from:
input_shape = (224,224,3)

to:
input_shape = (32, 32, 6)

error:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "vgg19" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 32, 32, 6), found shape=(None, 32, 32, 3)


You need to update the first convolutional layer to accept an input channel of 6 in this case.

Where does that update occur? I replaced the input channels from 3 to 6 of the input shape and I got the stated error.

From the error message, it seems that your input tensor has only 3 channels (RGB image ?).

They have 6 channels and the shapes are consistent with what I supplied in the vgg layer
